# What is going wrong when I pass a boolean from a child to its parent component using React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm currently trying to revise the dropdown menu component on my Gatsby site so that it reports a boolean to its parent component, a navbar. I plan on using that boolean to trigger some conditional CSS in Emotion.

The boolean isOpen reports if the dropdown menu is open or not, so true means it's open, and false means it's not.

As of now, I'm using React Hooks to pass that data from the child to the parent component. It seems like I'm successfully passing data, but when I click the dropdown menu, it sends both a true and a false boolean value in rapid succession, even as the menu remains open.

How do I revise this code so that isOpen in the child component is correctly reported to the parent component?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const Child = ({ isExpanded }) => {
  const [expandState, setExpandState] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setExpandState(isOpen)
    isExpanded(expandState)
  })

  return(
    <dropdownWrapper>
      <button 
        {...isExpanded}
      />
      {isOpen && (
        <Menu>
          //menu items go here
        </Menu>
      )}
    </dropdownWrapper>
  )
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [expandState, setExpandState] = useState(false)

  const onExpand = (checkExpand) => {
    setExpandState(checkExpand)
  }

  return(
    <Dropdown 
     isExpanded={onExpand}
     onClick={console.log(expandState)}
    />
 )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out myself. Parent needed a useEffect to register the incoming boolean.

Fixed code for the parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [expandState, setExpandState] = useState(false)

  const onExpand = (checkExpand) => {
    setExpandState(checkExpand)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    onExpand(expandState)
  })

  return(
    <Dropdown 
     isExpanded={onExpand}
     onClick={console.log(expandState)}
    />
 )

}
```